# Error handling For SMTPClient

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

```
[SMTPClient
    deliverMailFrom: sender
    to: recipient
    text: message
    usingServer: 'mail.google.com']
        on: Error
        do:["Transcript show:'Sumthing went wrong'"].
```

If `SMTPClient` raises an `Error` saying `TelnetProtocolError` or `ConnectionTimedOut`.
What's the right way to just make the Transcript display my message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use a parameter in the #do: block to get information about the exception:

```
[SMTPClient
    deliverMailFrom: sender
    to: recipient
    text: message
    usingServer: 'mail.google.com']
        on: Error
        do:[:e | Transcript show: e].
```

The :e parameter in the #do: block is an instance of the error that has been raised.